# Length of VARCHAR in Teradata

Tags: sql, teradata, varchar

I'm trying to write a query that only includes customer numbers either six or seven digits long. The numbers are stored in a VARCHAR(30) field in Teradata. I've tried the following:

```
...
AND LENGTH(STAFF_NO) > 5
AND LENGTH(STAFF_NO) < 8
...
```

```
...
AND CHARACTER_LENGTH(STAFF_NO) > 5
AND CHARACTER_LENGTH(STAFF_NO) < 8
...
```

```
...
AND CHAR_LENGTH(STAFF_NO) > 5
AND CHAR_LENGTH(STAFF_NO) < 8
...
```

but all of these have returned no rows; the query, in each case, has only looked at the maximum length of the field (30) rather than the actual number of characters in it.

How can I filter so it only checks the number of *actual* characters in the field?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on how you want to handle the trailing / leading whitespace.

Include: `CHAR_LENGTH(STAFF_NO) BETWEEN 6 AND 7`
Exclude: `CHAR_LENGTH(TRIM(STAFF_NO)) BETWEEN 6 AND 7`

It shouldn't make a difference whether it's `VARCHAR` or `CHAR`.

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
LENGTH(TRIM(BOTH FROM STAFF_NO)) AS STAFF_NO_LENGTH
```

This removes empty spaces from either side of the string.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `CHARACTER_LENGTH` function to get length of character in `VARCHAR` column.

Cheers!!

Answer (score 0):

Each functions that you used should return the length of **column value** not the max length of the column itself. Probably, there are extra spaces at the end of STAFF_NO? Try adding a TRIM as follows:

```
AND CHARS(TRIM(STAFF_NO)) BETWEEN 6 AND 7
```